# algebraic connectivity of a tree

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, trees

Suppose that $T$ is a tree with $n$ vertices and $L$ is the Laplacian matrix of $T$ and $0=\mu_1 \leq \mu_2 \leq \cdots \leq \mu_n$ are laplacian eigenvalues.

I think the multiplicity of $\mu_2$ can not be large.

For example I want to prove that:

If the multiplicity of $\mu_2$ in a tree $T$ be larger than $n/4$, then $T$ is the star $K_{1,n−1}$.

Any help can be useful for me.